# Find Outlook Email using Email ID or Extended Property with VBA

Tags: vba, email, search, outlook, office365

With the MS Graph API, I can see an Outlook Email's ID and set custom properties (Single Value extended property - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Is there a way to find a specific email by searching on that EmailID or custom property with VBA? It doesn't seem like I can search those properties with '`Folder.Items.Restrict()`'

Also, once I get an email item, I'm able to see the custom property I set through MS Graph Api.

`oItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{10101010-1010-1010-C101-1010101010101010}/myCustomProp")`

But is there a way to query the inbox and find that specific email with VBA?

I tried Using Restrict() and PropertyAccessor but they don't seem to address my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Items.Find/Restrict` to search for a property using its DASL name. Use a query like

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{10101010-1010-1010-C101-1010101010101010}/myCustomProp" = 'some value'
```

Note that the DASL name must be quoted, so in VBA it will be

```
set item = SomeFolder.Items.Find("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{10101010-1010-1010-C101-1010101010101010}/myCustomProp"" = 'some value'")
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply! For some reason the 'SomeFolder.Items.Find' come back as nothing/null.

Comment: `SomeFolder` means an instance of the `MAPIFolder` object. You will need to use the relevant variable name.

Comment: Currently, I'm getting the folder variable like this. Do you see anything that might be wrong? The 'extProp' and 'value' variables are the property name ("http:/schemas.../myCustomProp") and the value of that property. 

`Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oName = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = oName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  
Set oItems = oFolder.Items
Set oMail = oItems.Find("@SQL=" & Chr(34) & extProp & Chr(34) & "='" & value & "'")`

Comment: That looks fine to me. Does it return an error?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the syntax is correct. Must be something else that is causing the Find to fail. The 'Find' doesn't error, it just returns Nothing. oMail is Nothing = True. The property name and value are correct though since I can read the property value with 'GetProperty'.

Comment: Are you sure the property name is correct and there is an item with that property set in the Inbox folder? Do you see it in OutlookSpy (select the message and click IMessage button)?

Comment: Checking in Outlook Spy, `0x0000001F` was added to the end of the DASL string for the custom property. So the Find works when I included that. It looks like this `@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{10101010-1010-1010-C101-1010101010101010}/myCustomProp/0x0000001F" = 'some value'`. Do you have an idea of why `0x0000001F` needs to be included? Anyway thanks so much for your help and suggestions!!

Comment: `0x001F` is the property type - is stands for `PT_UNICODE`. Usually, Outlook does not require property type for the string properties - it assumes string if the type is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Binary properties (like `EntryID` and etc.) are not supported for searching items in Outlook. The best what you could do is to search items with a custom property. For example, you would use the following filter to search for a custom property named Mom's "Gift" that contains the word `pearls`:

```
filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
    "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/" _
    & "Mom%27s%20%22Gift%22" & Chr(34) & " like '%pearls%'"
```

Note, we have used the `Chr(34)` function solve the problem with double quotes. Read more about string comparisons in the [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) article.

To search for items that correspond to your conditions in an Outlook folder you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. You can read more about them in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

But if you need to search for items in multiple folders or subfolders you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class instead. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.